# Cannot access CSS in node.js html file

Tags: css, node.js, express, server

When I run my site the css does not load and I get the following error.

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:5000/server/nodeClient/public/css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I have reviewed 4 articles on stack overflow but I have not been able to fix the problem methods I have tried which have not worked included

- Removing comments from css header of the file
- Changing the path commands with many different combinations
- Using an alias on theapt.use command like below

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
```

My problem I think is to do with using the correct path as my public folder is in server/nodeClient/public/css.

## setup details

**The server.js command to configure that folder is**

```
app.use(express.static('../server/nodeClient/public/css'))
```

**The html link code is**

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../server/nodeClient/public/css/main.css" />
```

**The files are located here**

```
/server/server.js
/server/nodeClient/public/css/main.css
```

---

I have another app.use command that works below is the syntax

```
app.use(express.static('../client/build'));
```

this resides in {root}/client/build

---

## Full code sample below

### server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
//Dummy data
const SampleDocument = require('./nodeClient/data/documentSample');

// Connect Database
connectDB();
// Init Middleware   {to accept body data  res.send(req.body);}
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
// ROUTES
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/document', require('./routes/document'));
app.use('/api/confirmation', require('./routes/confirmation'));
/**********************************************************
MOST OF THE CLIENT PAGES ARE RUN IN REACT (from client directory). 
THE EMBED PAGE HAS TO BE IN NODE.JS
 These pages are designed to run in an iframe and 
therefore cannot be run in react som must be created
in ejs.
*/


app.use(express.static('../server/nodeClient/public/css'))

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/nodeClient/views'));
app.get('/embed/:docId', (req, res) => {
    res.render('embed', {
        data: {
            docId: req.params.docId,
            name: SampleDocument.title,
            document: SampleDocument,
        },
    });
});

/* *****************************************************************
{npm run dev)
localhost/3000: App run from /client                &   server run from /server
localhost/5000: App run from /client/build      &   server run from /server

To run in localhost/5000 ensure the {npm run build} has built an updated server build first
*/
app.use(express.static('../client/build'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html')));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on Port: ${PORT}`));
/*
When the react client is run proxy is run (in client/package.json)
The traffic goes like the

traffic arrives at localhost/5000 
 {if page exists on 3000 (the client)}{
    load client locahost/3000/mypage
    else (if page exists on 5000 (the server){
        load server locahost/5000/mypage
    }
}
*/
```

### embed.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../server/nodeClient/public/css/main.css" />

        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
            integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <title>Infoshot Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Name of document (from json.docData) : <%= data.document.title%></p>
        <div class="container">
            <%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>
            <main class="blue">
                <div class="test-box-medium blue">sample</div>
            </main>
            <footer class="green">
                <div class="test-box-medium green">sample</div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### main.css

```
#vertical-list-paragraph-1 {
    background: lightgray;
    color: lightgray;
}

.word-title {
    color: black;
}

.decision {
    flex-grow: 4;
    padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
}

.embedCode {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 3rem;
}

.container-flex-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container-flex-column-card {
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.container-flex-column-spacebetween {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.container-flex-column-center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container-flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.container-flex-row-valign {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: baseline;
}
.container-flex-row-cardtop {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 3px 3px;
}
.container-flex-row-spacebetween {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.container-flex-row-center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container-flex-row-align-baseline {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: baseline;
}
.container-flex-row-card {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
}
.container-flex-row-stretch {
    flex-grow: 4;
}

.container-flex-width-1 {
    width: 30%;
}

.container-flex-width-2 {
    flex-grow: 2;
}

.container-flex-width-3 {
    flex-grow: 3;
}

.container-img-full {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}

.container-full-width {
    min-width: 40px;
}

i {
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.container-child-list {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}

.container-paragraph {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.container-decisionBox {
    flex-grow: 4;
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.container-word {
    border-radius: 4px;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
}

input:not([type]),
input[type='text']:not(.browser-default) {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
}

.chapter-text > input[type='text'],
.page-text > input[type='text'],
.paragraph-text > input[type='text'],
.word-text > input[type='text'] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    color: #f8f8ff;
}

.chapter-text > input[type='text'] {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    height: 2.2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.page-text > input[type='text'] {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.paragraph-text > input[type='text'] {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
    color: #636b6f;
}

.word-text > input[type='text'] {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 0.8rem;
    color: #f8f8ff;
    z-index: -1;
}

.urlForm {
    z-index: 2;
}

.border {
    border: 1px black solid;
}
.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}
.border-green {
    border: 2px green solid;
}
.border-green-thick {
    border: 8px green solid;
}
.border-yellow {
    border: 2px yellow solid;
}

.margin-medium {
    margin: 5rem;
}

.margin-left {
    margin: 0.4rem;
}

.margin-left-xx {
    margin: 0.2rem;
}

.margin-bottom-xx {
    margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
}

.margin-none {
    margin: 0;
}

.padding-pt5 {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.padding-header {
    padding: 0.9rem 0.9rem 0.9rem 0.9rem;
}

.padding-3 {
    padding: 3rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.padding-3-px {
    padding: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.padding-thick-sides {
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
}

.padding-medium-sides {
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.padding-none {
    padding: 0;
}

.width-30pct {
    width: 70%;
}

.width-33pct {
    width: 33%;
}

.width-100-pct {
    width: 100%;
}

.width-100-pct-min {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
}

.width-500-px {
    width: 800px;
}

.width-flex-grow-1 {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.width-flex-grow-2 {
    flex-grow: 2;
}

.width-flex-grow-3 {
    flex-grow: 3;
}

.height-1 {
    min-height: 1rem;
}

.height-2 {
    min-height: 2rem;
}

.height-5 {
    min-height: 5rem;
}

.align-center {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

html {
    font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.h2 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
h3.contents-section {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin: 1rem 0rem 0.3rem 0rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}
h4.contents-item {
    margin: 1rem 0rem 0rem 0rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0rem 0rem 0.5rem 2rem;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.text-align-center {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0rem 0rem 2rem 0rem;
    font-weight: 200;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
li.indented {
    margin: 1rem 3rem 1rem 3rem;
}
li.indented-2 {
    margin: 0.5rem 0rem 0.5rem 5rem;
}
li.bullets {
    font-weight: 200;
    margin: 1rem 0rem 1rem 3rem;
    list-style-type: disc;
}
li.bullets-indented {
    margin: 1rem 3rem 1rem 3rem;
}
li.bullets-indented-2 {
    margin: 0.5rem 0rem 0.5rem 5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.text-left {
    text-align: left;
}

.text-right {
    text-align: right;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.text-bottom {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.text-size-x {
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0.2rem;
    margin: 0;
}

.text-size-xx {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    margin: 0;
}

.text-size-xxx {
    font-size: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    margin: 0;
}

.table-side-header {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 5rem;
}

.contents-page-number {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.text-white {
    color: white;
    background: white;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input[type='text'] {
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.title-page {
    padding: 8px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 3px 3px;
}

.title-chapter {
    padding: 8px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}

.title-paragraph {
    padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
}

.title-word {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.chapter-text,
.page-text,
.paragraph-text,
.word-text {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    color: #f8f8ff;
}

.chapter-text {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    height: 2.2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.page-text {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.paragraph-text {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
    color: #636b6f;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.word-text {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 0.6rem;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 0 0 25px 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.word-text:hover {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 0.6rem;
    color: blue;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 0 0 25px 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.material-icons {
    color: lightblue;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
}

.material-icons:hover {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #ee6e73;
}

i .handle {
    margin: auto;
    width: 15px;
}

.btn-small {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/* This file contains styles used for rapid prototyping only */
.test-box-medium-red,
.test-box-medium-blue,
.test-box-medium-green {
    min-width: 5rem;
    min-height: 3rem;
}

.test-box-medium-red,
.test-box-medium .red {
    background: red;
}

.test-box-medium-blue,
.test-box-medium .blue {
    background: blue;
}

.test-box-medium-green,
.test-box-medium .greem {
    background: green;
}

.test-box-nowidth {
    width: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
}

.test-flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

/* CSS reset code */
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

button {
    border: 0;
    background: inherit;
}

/* High level CSS defaults for rem */
a {
    color: red;
}

/* NO MORE HERE */
```

Comment: Whatever path you set in `.static()` becomes the root path in the browser. So `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />`

Comment: thank you! I am looking into that now

Comment: such a small piece of knowlege. I changed the ejs file to href="/css/main.css" and it works. I thought every combination but it works now - thanks! If you submit an answer I tick it as complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you set in .static() becomes the root path in the browser. So

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../server/nodeClient/public/css/main.css" />` to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" />`